# Bevel causes issues

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I have a cylinder with some Boolean modifiers , all applied , i have added proximity loops to some of them and as all Hard surface Projects have it , this one also needs a Bevel modifier which i added and here is the difference between **Before-Bevel-Edge** and **After-Bevel-Edge**
Providing Link for Reference to the original file

[image]

so , **Q: How To Fix this?**

[image]

[image]

**Edit** - The check box **Clamp Overlap** is intentionally so that i can control the bevel amount but if i see in josh gambrels tutorial on this thing , he doesn't have any such problem

Comment: how does your topology look like? maybe share your file

Comment: there's a checkbox in your screenshot, clamp overlap. If you check that it prevents the overlap, but also limits your offset. Isn't your object already beveled? Try also to increase the limitation angle.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz I was watching Josh Gambrels Hard Surface Modelling tutorial and i have disabled the Clamp overlap and reduced the Bevel Amount as mentioned in the tutorial and He didnot have any overlapping problem when he did the same thing...

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz i did not bevel it but YEAH!! looks like it is , could this be the problem , probably while applying the Booleans , i might've messed the bevel modifier?

Comment: @moonboots shared the file....

Comment: your angles are not made of just one edge, it's already beveled, so your modifier also bevel these edges

Comment: @moonboots I have Recovered a previous Autosave And found out that actually you are correct that my edges are already beveled and I have by mistake applied the modifier so write the awnsere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angles are not made of just one edge, they are already beveled:

[image]

So your modifier will double-bevel these edges and mess everything up with overlapping faces.

You can fix that by a *Merge by Distance* for example (be careful to not merge what you don't wnat to merge though).